# How can I get back web.py's stdout log when running under Apache/mod_wsgi?

Tags: logging, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi, web.py

I developed a web.py application and tested it a lot under stand-alone mode (running myapp.py from the command line) and its stdout output was much useful for debugging. Now I'm running it under Apache/mod_wsgi and lots of things don't work. For instance, my basic auth scheme, which used to work, always refuses the username/passwords it's given. The first thing I need is to be able to look at the debug messages I used to have. But the script's output is nowhere to be found.

How can I have "debug prints" again?

I don't want to ask about specific issues in my app until I have that much sorted out.

Comment: What version of mod_wsgi are you using? Make sure you are using mod_wsgi 3.0+ and 'print' output should end up in Apache error log.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class STDOUT(object):
    def __init__(self, next):
        self.next = next
        self.file = open('stdout.txt', 'w')
    def write(self, thing):
        self.file.write(thing)
        l.append(thing)
        self.next.write(thing)

>>> import sys
>>> s = STDOUT(sys.stdout)
>>> sys.stdout = s
>>> l = []
>>> print 4
4
>>> l
['4', '\n']
```

Comment: Doesn't work inside web.py. I used a condensed version of your code that doesn't write to the "previous" stdout, and doesn't append to an internal array. Nothing goes into the file.

Comment: I cannot understand why this should not work.. It worked all the years for me. Maybe some ImportError occurs? have you put a try:except: around the whole module and wrote to a file somewhere? You may use traceback.print_exc(file= ...) to print out an error.